# How to get RDF data returned by remote HTTP IRI through linux curl (e.g. DBpedia, GENEPIO ...)?

Tags: linux, sparql, rdf, linked-data, iri

I know that the following remote HTTP IRI can be parsed directly with 'curl http://xxx' because they return RDF data directly:

- https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
- http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
- http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#
- ...

[image]

But I don't know how the following remote HTTP IRI can be parsed directly, because they don't return RDF data directly:

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Resource_Description_Framework
- http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GENEPIO_0100155
- http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/NCBITaxon_2697049
- ...

[image]

[image]

How to get RDF data returned by remote HTTP IRI through `linux curl` (e.g. DBpedia, GENEPIO ...)  ?

Best regards

Comment: you should read about content negotiation and request headers as well as redirects in `curl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `Accept` header to specify which [MIME types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) you accept/prefer:

```
curl -L -H "Accept: text/turtle; q=1.0, application/rdf+xml; q=0.5" http://dbpedia.org/resource/Resource_Description_Framework
```

In this case, you would prefer Turtle (relative quality factor of 1.0) over RDF/XML (0.5).

(The option `-L` lets curl follow redirects. For example, from `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Resource_Description_Framework` to `http://dbpedia.org/data/Resource_Description_Framework.ttl`.)